# Finding and downloading images from websites using urllib2

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, image

I'm writing a small program that given an http address, it will find and download the images within. My current situation is this:

```
import urllib2, html

class HTMLNode(object):
    def __init__(self,tag,attr,content,closed=True):
        self.tag = tag
        self.attr = attr
        self.content = content
        self.closed = closed

    def istext(self):
        return self.tag == '_text_'

    def tostring(self):
        if self.istext(): 
            return self.content
        ret = '<'+self.tag
        for k, v in self.attr.items():
            ret += ' '+k+'="'+v+'"'
        ret += '>'
        if self.closed:
            for c in self.content:
                ret += c.tostring()
            ret += '</'+self.tag+'>'
        return ret

    def find_by_tag(self,tag):
            ret = []
            if self.tag == tag: ret += [self]
            if not self.istext():
                for c in self.content:
                    ret += c.find_by_tag(tag)
            return ret

def imagegrab(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    output = open(url, 'wb')
    output.write(response.read())
```

The missing link is finding a way to use the "find_by_tag" function of the HTMLNode class so that the program will scan for the "" tag and download the pics from the website. Can anybody help me with that?

Comment: You tagged this with Python 3 but are using `urllib2` (a Python 2 stdlib library). Either the tag is wrong or you are using `urllib` instead. :-)

Comment: I am using Python3 _and_ urllib2, I've never had any problems with that!

Comment: From the Python 2 [`urllib2` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html): *The `urllib2` module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named `urllib.request` and `urllib.error`.* Sorry to be so incredulous, but *there is no `urllib2` in python 3*.

Comment: Have you installed `urllib2` separately?

Comment: No, but when I runtest the program I get no errors at all, I just need the part needed to actually download the images.

Comment: Then something is wrong, because `import urllib2` in a standard Python 3 install will raise an error. Either you're never actually running the bit of the program that tries to import urllib2, or you're not using Python 3.

Comment: @test123: What does `import sys; print sys.version` tell you?

Comment: 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] What the hell...I've installed Python3, not 2!

Comment: You probably have both versions installed, and are invoking the script with something like `python foo`. That will look through the directories stored in your PATH environment variable to find `python.exe`, and if the Python2 installation directory is ahead of the Python3 one then Python2 will be launched. You can either use the full path to the executable (e.g. `c:/python33/python.exe`) or change your PATH.

Comment: @katrielalex I'm using Mac OS X, not Windows

Answer (score 2):

Other people have already done this work for you. Specifically, take a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), which is an HTML parsing library for Python. You would do

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(...)
for img in soup("img"):
    print img.src
```

or similar; obviously the library is much more powerful than that.

You could also consider using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which is a wrapper for the urllib family of libraries with a beautifully simple API. For that you would do

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text)
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to use urllib2 since it's preinstalled.

Comment: @test123-- why does it need to be preinstalled, you can't parse html with standard library.

Comment: @root [Actually, you can](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/html.parser.html) -- although BeautifulSoup is better for a number of reasons.

Comment: @katrielalex -- well, yes, in theory. it really doesn't handle any real world html.